# Can a person have 5 hearts like Kakuzu?

Tags: naruto

It is shown in the Anime that Kakuzu from Akatsuki has 5 hearts which he steals from the person he kills. Also he dies only when all hearts are destroyed. So can another person have 5 hearts like him or only he has that ability?

Answer (score 2):

In the real world? Yes, this might be possible  [read this](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/human-biology/two-lungs-one-heart1.htm)

In Naruto? I doubt there will be another but yes the possibility is there. Kakuzu decided to get more hearts due to his stitching power. There might be more ninja's that have a similar power that could do this. Then again the chances are slim that another ninja would do the same thing.